# Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died "Physical Memory Dump"

Tags: ios, memory, swift2, phphotolibrary

I'm trying to make a photo album but I always get this error about memory and I don't know how to resolve it

I have a collection view to display all photos from the album, if the album doesn't exist I make one

2015-11-30 09:41:22.208 PhotoGallery[4609:1586199] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2015-11-30 09:41:22.213 PhotoGallery[4609:1586199] [Crashlytics] Version 3.4.1 (92)
2015-11-30 09:42:08.492 PhotoGallery[4609:1586456] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died
2015-11-30 09:42:08.629 PhotoGallery[4609:1586199] Received memory warning.

This is the link to app https://github.com/krojas/PhotoGallary

the specific file https://github.com/krojas/PhotoGallary/blob/master/PhotoGallery/ViewController.swift

The app works ok while the album has few photos if not the memory goes to heaven

Thanks a lot and I hope that you understand me

Comment: I improve the photo using a function that scale the photo because the size of the photo was 2448 × 3264    1.3 MB, before save it I change the size to 480 × 640    59 KB  and now it's working ok until now, I'll update the code on github maybe someone wants to check it

Comment: That was a good solution for now